# How to create a soap-enc:Array parameter with python zeep?

Tags: python, xml, wsdl, suds, zeep

I have to construct a SOUP method Agw_typeGenerarDespachoIn from [wsdl](http://sandbox.coordinadora.com/agw/ws/guias/1.6/server.php?wsdl)

```
<xsd:complexType name="Agw_typeGenerarDespachoIn">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="guias" type="soap-enc:Array"/>
<xsd:element name="margen_izquierdo" type="xsd:float"/>
<xsd:element name="margen_superior" type="xsd:float"/>
<xsd:element name="tipo_impresion" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="usuario" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="clave" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I construct the param guias of type soap-enc:Array

```
array_type = self.client.get_type('ns1:Array')
guias = array_type()
values = xsd.AnyObject(array_type, array_type(_attr_1={'guias': '98516000037'}))
Agw_typeGenerarDespachoIn = self.factory.Agw_typeGenerarDespachoIn(guias=values,
                                                                   margen_izquierdo=float(0),                                                                                  
                                                                   margen_superior=float(0),
                                                                   tipo_impresion=unicode('LASER'),              
                                                                   usuario=unicode(self.usuario),
                                                                   clave=unicode(self.clave))
```

I get return

```
'`list`' object has no attribute '`_xsd_name`'
```

If i try with other value for param guias like

```
guia = dict(item='98516000056')
```

i get the  return error

```
TypeError: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}Array() got an unexpected keyword argument 'item'. Signature: `_value_1: ANY[], arrayType: xsd:string, offset: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}arrayCoordinate, id: xsd:ID, href: xsd:anyURI, _attr_1: {}`
```

So i try with the sugered value "_value_1"

```
    guia = dict(_value_1=['98516000056'])
```

And get the error

```
Any element received object of type 'unicode', expected lxml.etree._Element or __builtin__.dict or zeep.xsd.valueobjects.AnyObject
```

I have tried different ways to build the soup-enc:Array parameter but I always get an error. You know how I can fix it. I appreciate all the help you can give me

Answer (score 0):

My mistake in creating the array in the Agw_typeGenerarDespachoIn method of the Coordinadora transporter was to try to create the Array type. Actually the type Array should be taken as a normal python array.

```
guias = []
```

String elements must be created that will be added to the array.

```
guias_type = client.get_element('ns1:string')
```

Finally, append elements string type to the array.

```
for remesa in remesas:
        guias.append(xsd.AnyObject(guias_type, remesa))
```

Put all params in the method

```
Agw_typeGenerarDespachoIn = factory.Agw_typeGenerarDespachoIn(guias=guias, #    array   Codigos de guia a las que se les va a generar un despacho (array de strings)
                                                                   margen_izquierdo=float(0), # float   Margen izquierdo para la generacion del PDF, en caso que el tipo impresion seleccionado genere un PDF
                                                                   margen_superior=float(0), # float    Margen superior para la generacion del PDF, en caso que el tipo impresion seleccionado genere un PDF
                                                                   tipo_impresion=unicode('LASER'), #   string  Tipo de impresion que se desea obtener las opciones son (LASER, LASER_RESUMIDA, POS_PDF, POS_PLANO).
                                                                   usuario=unicode(self.usuario), # string  Usuario asignado. Ej: prefijo.usuario
                                                                   clave=unicode(self.clave) # string   Clave codificada con el algoritmo sha256.
                                                                   )
print Agw_typeGenerarDespachoIn
response = client.service.Guias_generarDespacho(Agw_typeGenerarDespachoIn)
```